# Compare Today Date to Reserved Date in ES6 ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to compare todays date to my reserved date.
The value of my reserved date is `2020-10-01T17:00:00.000Z`. I'm trying to put a condition on my button that if `reserved_date < = today`, then button should be disabled

```
today = new Date()

 <Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained" disabled={value.reserved_date <= today}>
     Submit
 </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So either you have to turn today in to a iso string and do the comparison or make a date object from `reserved_date`

1. first point

   ```
   today = new Date().toISOString();
   ....disabled={value.reserved_date <= today}>
   ```
2. second point

   ```
   ....disabled={new Date(value.reserved_date) <= today}>
   ```

Comment: Thank you. How about i will disabled the button if `reserved_date` is 2 days from now? Thank you